# Gitlab msbuild issue in Build server - Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, nuget, gitlab

I have solution which is absolutely working fine in my local system. But same code is throwing following error when the build triggers in the Build server. Could you kindly help with this?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3245: **Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Company.Common.SC.Data, Version=2.5.3.32715, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.** [C:\glr\builds\7a6e3c3e\0\Company\Product\Company-sm-mvc\Company.Product.MVC.Models\Company.Product.MVC.Models.csproj]
          For SearchPath "C:\glr\builds\7a6e3c3e\0\Company\Product\Company-sm-mvc\packages\Company.Common.SC.MVC.Library.1.7.0\lib\net45".
          Considered "C:\glr\builds\7a6e3c3e\0\Company\Product\Company-sm-mvc\packages\Company.Common.SC.MVC.Library.1.7.0\lib\net45\Company.Common.SC.Data.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\glr\builds\7a6e3c3e\0\Company\Product\Company-sm-mvc\packages\Company.Common.SC.MVC.Library.1.7.0\lib\net45\Company.Common.SC.Data.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\glr\builds\7a6e3c3e\0\Company\Product\Company-sm-mvc\packages\Company.Common.SC.MVC.Library.1.7.0\lib\net45\Company.Common.SC.Data.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "..\packages\Company.Common.SC.Data.2.5.3\lib\net45\Company.Common.SC.Data.dll",
            but its name "Company.Common.SC.Data, Version=2.5.3.23193, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            didn't match the expected name "Company.Common.SC.Data, Version=2.5.3.32715, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
```

I believe something wrong with the `Company.Common.SC.Data` nuget library. The nuget lib is created using the nuget package manager, while creating the package we have given the version number `2.5.3`, but not sure how the subversion is getting added. Please see the last line of the error.

```
 Considered "..\packages\Company.Common.SC.Data.2.5.3\lib\net45\Company.Common.SC.Data.dll",
            but its name "Company.Common.SC.Data, Version=2.5.3.23193, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            didn't match the expected name "Company.Common.SC.Data, Version=2.5.3.32715, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
```

**Update 1 :**

Nuspec for Company.Common.SC.Data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Updated for 8.0 and includes additional library code related to Dacron, Terathane and other sites that added to core capabilities.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>sitecore data website common</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: have you checked the setting on your nuspec of `Company.Common.SC.Data`?

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Have updated the nuspec file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and able to fix it. The issue was the the nuget project dll were building with AssemblyVersion number. Something like this.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.7.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.7.0")]
```

Due to this, subversion is being added (1.7.1.354567) in the project reference when we added it into our project via nuget feed.

I just removed the `*` and build the nuget solution and then created the nuget package of **Company.Common.SC.Data** and then i referred it again in my project. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue but are not using NuGet (not feasible for us). In our case its due to project X referencing DLL Y which in turn references DLL Z (X doesn't reference Z directly). We have copy local true & specific version false in all references. We just output all dependent DLLs into a common bin folder.

Consider that the current version of Z is 1.1.1.1.
We build Y and it places its version (1.1.1.1) into the bin folder also.
We build Z again - its version is now 1.1.1.2 and copied into the bin folder - so we have Y = 1.1.1.1 (which expected 1.1.1.1 of Z at the time it was built)
If X is now built then it will grab Y's DLL from the bin folder (1.1.1.2) BUT not Z.

Visual Studio builds handle this correctly by grabbing the latest version of Y & Z from the bin folder, not caring about the version as 'specific version' is set to false.

However msbuild moans because it seems to ignore this and expects the specific version of Z that the current version of Y expects (1.1.1.1) and logs the 'didn't match expected name' error. If we build Y again (to refresh the fact it needs 1.1.1.2 now of Z) then X includes the DLL fine.